# Use Arrows to Navigate through list / change Widget

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I am currently struggling to implement a "list" with two QR-Codes.
I want to change the shown QR code by pressing the arrows left and right to it.
"list" because currently I don't use a list view.

Currently it looks like this: [Current App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7msy.png)

The QR codes are within a ModalBottomSheet.

Here is my code so far:

```
void _onButtonPressed() {
    bool inAppQr = true;
    String _output = "QR 1";

    showModalBottomSheet(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    _output,
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                    width: 150,
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                        Colors.blueGrey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              inAppQr = false;
                              _output = "QR 1";
                            });
                          }),
                      inAppQr == true
                          ? PrettyQr(
                              typeNumber: 3,
                              size: 150,
                              data: 'Test',
                              errorCorrectLevel: QrErrorCorrectLevel.M,
                              roundEdges: true)
                          : PrettyQr(
                              typeNumber: 3,
                              size: 150,
                              data: 'Test 2',
                              errorCorrectLevel: QrErrorCorrectLevel.M,
                              roundEdges: true),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _output = "QR 2";
                              inAppQr = true;
                            });
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
          );
        });
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: wrap your container in a StatefulBuilder and just change the StateSetter name to something other than setState as that will override your main widget setState. After this, you should be fine with some if/else conditions.

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found thanks to Zeeshan Hussain!

I added a StatefulBuilder with the StateSetter newState
This code worked for me:

```
void _onButtonPressed() {
bool inAppQr = true;
String _output = "QR 1";

showModalBottomSheet(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter newState) {
          return Container(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    _output,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                    width: 150,
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                        Colors.blueGrey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                          onPressed: () {
                            newState(() {
                              inAppQr = true;
                              _output = "QR 1";
                            });
                          }),
                      inAppQr == true
                          ? PrettyQr(
                              typeNumber: 3,
                              size: 150,
                              data: 'Test',
                              errorCorrectLevel: QrErrorCorrectLevel.M,
                              roundEdges: true)
                          : PrettyQr(
                              typeNumber: 3,
                              size: 150,
                              data: 'Test 2',
                              errorCorrectLevel: QrErrorCorrectLevel.M,
                              roundEdges: true),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                          onPressed: () {
                            newState(() {
                              _output = "QR 2";
                              inAppQr = false;
                            });
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
          );
        },
      );
    });
```